# How to observe ParentViewController of UIViewController changes?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

How to observe ParentViewController of UIViewController changes?
I want to observe ParentViewController changes.

Comment: Please provide enough details that what you want and what you did

Comment: When you say parent, do you mean literally so, as in the context of view controller containment? Or do you mean it more loosely, as in the view controller that presented/pushed to the current view controller? And what sort of "changes" do you want to observe?

Comment: I want to observe property of UIViewController that is "UIViewController.ParentViewController"